# Searching a free alert framework for a java application

Tags: java, frameworks, alert

my first question here :)
I'm searching for an alert framework.
It should be able to do:

- sending alerts about multiple channels (E-mail, SMS, Real time monitor)
- should be easily configured. That means, alerts must be created without programming skills. Maybe in a xml-File or something like that.
- There must be a configuration file about the specific alerts. This file describe how to react when a specific alert occurs. Who should be notified and which format the alert message must have.
- must have an API that i can use in a java application.

I've not found something, that is able to do that. I've read, that the JMX Framework is able to do something like that, but I've no idea how. I would be happy about some ideas :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest is to use a logging framework.  Several exists.

The most actively maintained is [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), where you might find the [SMTPAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) an interesting starting point.